# Need to sort dates from Monthwise to datewise with apps script

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I have dates sorted by Month name in sheet that are not sorted Year wise. Also the format of dates is very difficult to handle; it is like MMMM, YYYY, MMMM, YYYY, MMMM, YYYY .........
Thus I am confused how to handle the sorting.

Here is an example of data in a cell

> JANUARY, 2016, JANUARY, 2017, JANUARY, 2018, JANUARY, 2019, JANUARY, 2020, FEBRUARY, 2016, FEBRUARY, 2017, FEBRUARY, 2018, FEBRUARY, 2019, FEBRUARY, 2020, FEBRUARY, 2021, MARCH, 2016, MARCH, 2017, MARCH, 2018, MARCH, 2019, APRIL, 2016, APRIL, 2017, APRIL, 2018, APRIL, 2019, MAY, 2016, MAY, 2017, MAY, 2018, MAY, 2019, JUNE, 2016, JUNE, 2017, JUNE, 2018, JUNE, 2019, JULY, 2016, JULY, 2017, JULY, 2018, JULY, 2019, AUGUST, 2016, AUGUST, 2017, AUGUST, 2018, AUGUST, 2019, SEPTEMBER, 2016, SEPTEMBER, 2017, SEPTEMBER, 2018, SEPTEMBER, 2019, OCTOBER, 2016, OCTOBER, 2017, OCTOBER, 2018, OCTOBER, 2019, NOVEMBER, 2015, NOVEMBER, 2016, NOVEMBER, 2017, NOVEMBER, 2018, NOVEMBER, 2020, DECEMBER, 2015, DECEMBER, 2016, DECEMBER, 2017, DECEMBER, 2018, DECEMBER, 2020

Please note this data gives all Januaries, then gives all Februaries and so on..

I want it sorted date wise so it should become Nov 2015, Dec 2015, Jan 2016 and so on. Another difficult issue is that some months may be missing in data so I can't just consider it like Nov 2015 to July 2021. That is why I need a script but am really stuck at what algorithm I should use and there is no help online.

Here is the sheet with data in column A
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJS90Nen6bNu6oJNlpuKscaUGVJdLibU8PVJ9QFI0vM/edit#gid=0

Comment: It is not clear to me how this is setup in the sheet? All in one cell? Month in A and year in B? Can you share a sheet/screenshot?

Comment: Above data I shared is in all in cell A1

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = 'JANUARY, 2016, JANUARY, 2017, JANUARY, 2018, JANUARY, 2019, JANUARY, 2020, FEBRUARY, 2016, FEBRUARY, 2017, FEBRUARY, 2018, FEBRUARY, 2019, FEBRUARY, 2020, FEBRUARY, 2021, MARCH, 2016, MARCH, 2017, MARCH, 2018, MARCH, 2019, APRIL, 2016, APRIL, 2017, APRIL, 2018, APRIL, 2019, MAY, 2016, MAY, 2017, MAY, 2018, MAY, 2019, JUNE, 2016, JUNE, 2017, JUNE, 2018, JUNE, 2019, JULY, 2016, JULY, 2017, JULY, 2018, JULY, 2019, AUGUST, 2016, AUGUST, 2017, AUGUST, 2018, AUGUST, 2019, SEPTEMBER, 2016, SEPTEMBER, 2017, SEPTEMBER, 2018, SEPTEMBER, 2019, OCTOBER, 2016, OCTOBER, 2017, OCTOBER, 2018, OCTOBER, 2019, NOVEMBER, 2015, NOVEMBER, 2016, NOVEMBER, 2017, NOVEMBER, 2018, NOVEMBER, 2020, DECEMBER, 2015, DECEMBER, 2016, DECEMBER, 2017, DECEMBER, 2018, DECEMBER, 2020';

let res = a.split(', ').map((el, i, arr) => i % 2 === 0 ? `${el} ${arr[i+1]}` : null).filter(el => el).sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)).join(', ');

console.log(res);
```

Explanation:

```
let res = a.split(', ') // split cell value into array using separator
  .map((el, i, arr) => i % 2 === 0 ? `${el} ${arr[i+1]}` : null) // for each even array index `i` (0, 2, ..) take current element (month value) and next value with index `i+1` (year value); for each odd index (1, 3, ..) return `null`
  .filter(el => el) // filter out `null` values
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(a) - new Date(b)) // sort array by date
  .join(', ') // join array back to string using separator
```

Comment: Thank you Kos. This works like magic for me as I don't understand how you have done it. Many questions in my mind. if you can answer some, would be great.
1- I understand >= means greater than/ equal to but what is meaning of => in your code.
2- I understand map method as something.map(function(name){return} but you have just put (el, i, arr) and did it. What are el, i and arr and how do those work here?
3- What is significance of ${}
4- What is meaning of ': null'